# Why mutex (std::mutex) is heavy?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, mutex

Quite often on this site, other forums I read phrases like "mutex is heavy, better use something else". But I can't really find explanation  why it's heavy? Also, if we are talking about standard C++11 before C++20, we basically have only std::mutex, used with locks or  condition_variable, to make something thread-safe, I expected something from std be quite efficient, especially if it's the only tool(before C++20) to make some task, thread-safety in this case.
So why mutexes and particularly std::mutex is heavy? And what we as C++ developers should use instead? Something from boost?

Comment: Can you give an example of someone saying a mutex is "heavy"? We are lacking context here of what they were trying to do and what the alternative was.

Comment: Heavy compared to what? In which situation? If all you want is to increment an integer, you can be better served with an `atomic<int>`.

Comment: `std::mutex` can be considered heavy because it is typically implemented using system calls, while say `std::atomic` does not.

Comment: Mutexes are "heavy" compared to "not having mutexes" but if you need one, you need one, no way around it. If you can restructure to avoid them and the code is still correct, congratulations. If not, the cost of these is small, annoying, but necessary.

Comment: What is? The locking?

Comment: I use `std::mutex`, until I've determined that it's a performance concern after profiling.  Then I consider alternatives such as `std::atomic` and if the effort (and trickier, harder to maintain code) is worth the performance gain.  But I've found a better general approach is to try for immutability for all cross-thread objects, then it's a non-issue.

Comment: @Eljay but if I have some collection on which different thread can operate insert,delete and view operation, atomic will not help unfortunatelly

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes,with int it's easy, but if we are  talking about collection,like vector or map

Comment: If the collection and its items are immutable, then you cannot insert or delete.  You can only view.  And for view, you don't need a mutex, or atomic.

Comment: @Eljay yes, but they are mutable

Comment: Then you should use a mutex.

Comment: "*Quite often on this site, other forums I read phrases like "..."*" - I have been on this site, and many others, for many many years, and have NEVER heard such a phrase before.

Answer (score 11):

Mutexes are considered "heavy" because they are often believed to result in a syscall, i.e. a round-trip to the kernel. A trip to the kernel takes on the order of 1,000+ CPU cycles due to context switching between privileged and unprivileged code.

In many OSes these days mutexes are optimized to not go to the kernel until a contention occurs. For example, in Linux it's implemented using a futex ("fast userspace mutex"), in Windows - SRW lock. However, once there is a contention, there *will* be a trip to the kernel. And once a thread needs to wait, it will be "put to sleep" by the OS and there will be a significant delay between the moment the lock is released and the time the thread is scheduled to be executed again.

If you need synchronization, sometimes looping on a simple `atomic` can be sufficient. If contentions are rare and short, then you can achieve better performance with a "spin lock", i.e. looping until certain condition is met. Even if you loop 10000 times, it can be faster than a single syscall.

In practice, however, a mutex will provide adequate balance between performance and convenience. So I wouldn't worry about it unless you are counting nanoseconds (as in HFT or real-time applications).

Comment: Before using spinlocks, people should read [this](https://matklad.github.io/2020/01/02/spinlocks-considered-harmful.html) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/locking/spinlocks.txt), and [this](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=189711&curpostid=189723).

Answer (score 6):

`std::mutex` was designed to be a light-weight portable wrapper around the operating system's native mutex facility. If your goal was to invoke those facilities, `mutex` introduces only a very negligible overhead over calling the OS-native API directly.

However, depending on what your use case is, using an OS facility might not be the optimal solution. For instance, to protect data from concurrent access, you could also write your own lock from lower-level primitives like `std::atomic`. This will however be a *different kind* of lock algorithm. In particular, `std::mutex` will put a waiting thread to sleep if the mutex can't be obtained right away, which is something you cannot do without talking to the OS. In some cases though, such a simpler locking algorithm is sufficient to get the job done. A popular example here are cases where lock contention is expected to occur only in rare cases.

That being said, such thoughts get you quite deep into expert-level concurrency programming. Unless you have specific concerns that require worrying about micro-optimizations like rolling your own locking, `std::mutex` is the way to go and its overhead is well withing reasonable bounds for what it's doing.

Answer (score 5):

All kinds of synchronization is "heavy", and lock based is heavier than atomic.

https://github.com/markwaterman/MutexShootout

This person did a comparison between various mutex implementations.  A raw windows SWR lock was the fastest option, but the most recent std mutex they compared it to was the MSVC 2017 one.

I believe that `std::shared_mutex` is a windows SRW lock under the hood.

Do you need every last tiny percent of performance?  Then you should be profiling and swapping out mutexes.  If not, `std::mutex` is within 10s of percents of best options, and will probably continue to be iterated on and supported.

Atomic integer operations are generally cheaper than a mutex lock, but the rules are more complex.  In addition, atomic operations cause non-local slowdowns in your code, as it causes cache lines to be cleared to avoid someone else having the wrong value.

In my experience, until you get to extreme situations, you can do algorithm changes to get far more than 10%s of performance changes.  And when you really, really need performance, you will probably be stripping out mutexes as much as possible anyhow; even the fastest mutex isn't fast enough for really high performance situations.

Optimization is fungible; you can spend your development effort making code faster when you identify a bottleneck.  Don't write code that is prematurely pessimized; but 10s of percent hit from using std mutex over the alternative locks is not usually large enough to be that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mutexes are expensive in the same sense that copying is expensive. Meaning if you can obviate the need for a copy, that is better than having to copy. But if you need a copy, there is no way around that. The same goes for `std::mutex`. Not because `std::mutex` is inefficient, but because mutexes are inherently expensive.